# IndexError : no such group

Tags: python, python-re

I tried to replace the elements in `right_guesses`, with `right_guesses[m.end(-1)]`.

```
from all_wrd import words
import random
import re

global n
global total

total = 3

class Hangman:
    def __init__(self, user_guess, secret_word):
        self.user_guess = user_guess
        self.secret_word = secret_word

    def checker(self,user):
        n = 0
        user_guess = user
        right_guesses = (["-"] * len(secret_word))

        while True:
            try:
                if user in secret_word:
                    print("you got it right")
                    for m in re.finditer(user, secret_word):
                        right_guesses[m.end(-1)] = user
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/def_projects/guesser.py", line 81, in <module>
Hangman.checker(self=None,user=user_guess)

File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/def_projects/guesser.py", line 25, in checker
right_guesses[m.end(-1)] = user

IndexError: no such group
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```py
right_guesses[m.end(0)] = user
```

`m.end(n)` accesses the `n`th group from the end of the matches, counting backwards, so `m.end(0)` is the last group, `m.end(1)` is the second last group, etc. Accessing the -1th group from the end counting backwards doesn't make sense.

This is different from normal python list indexing, where `list[-1]` would indeed give you the last element of a list.

Comment: It would have started 1 index after. Let's say the word is "abc" and the display is "..." Without the -1. When the user guesses "b", it would've displayed "..b" instead of ".b.". but when ever i use the `m.end(-1)` it shows the error above.